# NSSpeechSynthesizer does not write AIFF-file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode5

using Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.4,
    consider the following code snippets:

```
- (IBAction)speak:(id)sender        // text to loudspeaker, this works
{
   [self setup];         // provide the synthesizer with its parameters
   [speaker startSpeakingString: [textEntry stringValue]];
}


- (IBAction)storeSpeech:(id)sender  // does not work
{
   [self setup];         // provide the synthesizer with its parameters
   [NSURL *outputFile =
          [NSURL URLWithString:@"speech.aiff"];
   [speaker startSpeakinString: [textEntry stringValue]
          toURL:outputFile];   // the aiff-file is not created, why not?
}
```

Method speak outputs to the computers speaker. This works ok.

Method storeSpeech does not create any aiff-file. WHY NOT?

Answer (score 1):

"speech.aiff" isn't much of a URL, is it?

Either use a URL that starts with file:// or use a path and a method that creates a file URL.

Comment: You are right of course, thank you. I now use [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"speech.aiff"]; which does what it is supposed to do. Thank you!